# Finding a label element and clicking on it

Tags: python, html, css, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
<label class="btn btn-default btn-sm ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="radio.activePane" btn-radio="1">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i>
    Datos
</label>
```

I'm trying to find this element and then click on it. However I can't find it and I don't know exactly why.

I have tried this code but I get NoSuchElementException. I would like to find it by the text if it is possible. The class and the rest of the tags may change.

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[contains(text(), 'Datos')]").click()`

Any ideas of how can I find the element and click on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either of the two below XPath expressions:
`//*[text()[contains(.,'Datos')]]` or `//label[contains(.,'Datos')]`

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()[contains(.,'Datos')]]").click()
```

or:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[contains(.,'Datos')]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `NoSuchElementException` you can try the [explicitWait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[contains(text(), 'Datos')]")))
element.click()
```

***OR***

```
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[normalize-space(),'Datos']")))
element.click()
```